# How to check if HTA is foreground window?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, hta

I'm trying to determine if an HTA is the foreground window.  The following PowerShell will normally identify the foreground window:

```
Add-Type @"
   using System;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   public class UserWindows {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
   }
"@

$a = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }
```

But, if the HTA is in the foreground, **no** process is returned.  (I.E. there is a MainWindowHandle, but there is no process!?)

The MSHTA process has an entirely different MainWindowHandle, but no window.

Process Hacker identifies the HTA window (frame or contents) as the mshta process.

How can I match up the HTA window and mshta.exe via script?  Alternatively, how can I get the MainWindowHandle of the HTA window without knowing if it is in front?

Answer (score 0):

The Foregroundwindow returned is not a mainwindowhandle of any process but just a window handle of mshta, you'll have to check all window handles.
I did manually with the tool cmdow.exe (had to convert the handle to hex) and got this for my example `The HTA helpomatic` :

```
> cmdow 0x14E0F46
Handle   Lev  Pid -Window status- Image    Caption
0x14E0F46 1 153048 Res Ina Ena Vis mshta    The HTA Helpomatic -- Presented by t
```

There should be better/more PowerShellish ways to enumerate the window handles but this changed script will use the mentioned [cmdow.exe](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/)

```
## Get-ForegrounWindow.ps1
Add-Type @"
   using System;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   public class UserWindows {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
   }
"@

while ($true -eq 'true') {
    $ForeGroundWin = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
    $handle = "0x{0:x}" -f $($ForeGroundWin.ToInt64())
    cmdow.exe $Handle /B /F
    Sleep -sec 5  
}
```

Sample output:

```
> .\Get-ForegrounWindow.ps1
0x15C04A2 1 127148 Res Act Ena Vis powershell Windows PowerShell
0x7F0DE4 1 135416 Res Act Ena Vis TextPad  TextPad - Q:\Test\2017-06\09\Get-ForegrounWindow.ps1
0x16205D0 1 121732 Res Act Ena Vis bash     usernamet@computer: ~
0x14E0F46 1 153048 Res Act Ena Vis mshta    The HTA Helpomatic -- Presented by the Microsoft Scripting Guys
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to avoid third-party tools (and I *really* don't want to be flagged as malware -- which is likely with CMDOW.EXE).

Comment: I've had no time to find another solution, it's just to show the principle to get **ALL** window handles and via that to get the originating process.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the answer from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c3cd3982-ffc5-4c17-98fc-a09c555e121c/get-all-child-window-titles?forum=winserverpowershell) to get this which does what I need:

```
Add-Type  @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
public class UserWindows {
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
      public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd,StringBuilder lpString, int cch);
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
}
"@

while(1) {
   $ForgroundWindow = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
   $FGWTitleLength = [UserWindows]::GetWindowTextLength($ForgroundWindow)
   $StringBuilder = New-Object text.stringbuilder -ArgumentList ($FGWTitleLength + 1)
   $null = [UserWindows]::GetWindowText($ForgroundWindow,$StringBuilder,$StringBuilder.Capacity)
   if ($StringBuilder.ToString() -match $HTAWindowTitleRegEx) {
      # Put further scripting here for when the HTA window is in front
   }
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Hope that helps someone.